# How to update react redux state Object of id - key value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a variable in my redux state that seems to be an Object of key as id and value as content, [image],
as you can see this state variable, let's call it `capacity`, is not an array or list but a plain object, and I want to increase one of the item property `availableCapacity` to be the value in my action payload by id, so here is what I can do

```
const updatedCapacity = {
   ...state.capacity[id],
        availableCapacity: state[id].availableCapacity + 1
   };
```

and my `updatedCapacity` will be look like

```
{
  active: true
  avaialbleCapacity: 31
  capacity: "2febf..."
  totalCapacityAvailable: 30
}
```

but then how could I find the element in my state by id then replace it with my modified `updatedCapacity`? I have tried below but instead, it added a new entry in my state.capacity in first example, and in 2nd example it added a new entry of key value "id", not my exact id of "2febfxxxx"...

```
case UPDATE_CAPACITY:
  return {
     ...state.capacity,
     updatedCapacity
  }
or
case UPDATE_CAPACITY:
  return {
     ...state.capacity,
     id: { updatedCapacity }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shallowly copy all state for the objects you are updating. You can use the `id` as a dynamic key.

```
case UPDATE_CAPACITY:
  return {
    ...state, // <-- copy current state
    [id]: {
      ...state[id], // <-- copy current element
      availableCapacity: state[id].availableCapacity + 1 // <-- increment capacity
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you! do what does `[id]` after `...state,` do here? I mean why would the `bracket` be here?

Comment: @KevDing Object property accessor. [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) a little bit down. If object is `state = { foo: 'bar', a: 0, b: 'test' }` and `id = 'foo'`, then `{ ...state, [id]: 'bizzbuzz' }` would result in `{ foo: 'bizzbuzz', a: 0, b: 'test' }`. Did my answer resolve your state updating issue?